# Shape appears different in Edit Mode and Object Mode

Tags: modeling

So this is my first model. And the shape appears different in Edit Mode and Object Mode.
[image]

[image]

Can someone please explain me why it is piking out like that?

Comment: Have you applied modifier? It can be turned off in edit mode but turned on again when in layout mode.

Comment: only mirror modifier

Answer (score 1):

it looks like one misplaced vertex. Try to fix it or use bisect at the modifier.
[image]